How to adapt the Balancer FlashSwap call to get profit in token A when only given outputAmount B of first swap?
According to https://docs.balancer.fi/reference/swaps/flash-swaps.html#example, I can make an arbitrage trade by calling batchSwap. The example shows that with the swap kind GivenIn, the assets list and the swap list, the balancer vault automatically executes the dual arbitrage swaps and sends the vault-leaving amount to the receiver. The example makes the trade between pool 1 and 2 and token A/B. Given amount is in token A, and profit is in token A.
How must I call the batch swap when I only have the given output amount of the first swap in token B, but want to get the profit in token A? I tried it with this configuration:
SwapKind: GIVEN_OUT
pools: [pool1, pool2]
assets: [A, B]
and first BatchSwapStep AssetInIdx = assets[0], AssetOutIdx = assets1
second BatchSwapStep AssetInIdx = assets1, AssetOutIdx = assets[0]
But this also gives me the profit in token B.
